# How to calculate accuracy of specific users in a program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a task to create a program that counts the weights of bags to see if they are correct. For this I have to calculate the total accuracy and the accuracy of each user that inputs data. I am fine with the total accuracy but cannot seem to do the user accuracy.

I have tried to use dictionaries lists and text files but I cannot seem to get my head around of  how to do it

```py
elif menuInput == 4 :
    if totalBags == 0:
        print('You cannot display accuracy as you have not entered any data')    
    elif totalBags != 0:
        totalAccuracy = (correctBags/totalBags)*100
        print('The total accuracy is', totalAccuracy, 'percent')
```

The total accuracy works as expected but I cannot do the user accuracy.  I want the output of the program to show.

User: name, bags counted, correct bags, accuracy %

User: name2, bags counted, correct bags, accuracy %

Comment: What expression have you tried to calculate this "user accuracy"? And what information are you storing in the dicts / text files?

Comment: Since there is no way to tell which bag belongs to which person I suggest we blame it all on Bob and set his accuracy to 0. Prove me wrong!

Comment: at the moment i am storing the user's name, weight of bag and a 1 if the weight if the weight is correct and a 0 if the weight is incorrect. I have not got round to calculating the user accuracy as i cannot assign the bags counted to a specific person. I want the output of the program to show. User: name, bags counted, correct bags, accuracy %